# Read-only file system in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

i try to open the camera with th opencv library using android studio but it is not opened and the message appeared was " it seems that your device does not support camera( or it is locked) application will be closed" on the emulator screen

this is my logcat

```js
09-09 19:39:17.436 11223-11223/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Have you set permission for file I/O and device access in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file? Also, as far as I know Android emulators don't support camera.

Comment: '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>'

Comment: this is the permissions that i added .... i am new in android developments but i saw many tutorials on the youtube and they can open the emulator's cam.

Comment: What API are you using to open the camera? Is it the ```highgui``` from the OpenCV framework or the Camera2 API from the Android framework? If ```highgui``` then no it will not work as such , you'll need to use Camera2 API and pass the frames to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you are using emulator, it will not allow writing a file to its file system, unless you use API ver 21 or below. (That's what I tried once and it works probably.)

AVD does support camera, try edit AVD -> Advanced parameters.

Comment: i was using API 22 ,, and based on your words i try to use API 21, the error is disappeared from the logcat but the emulator show me the message "unfortunately app_name has stopped"

Comment: There can be many reasons for that crash. If you suspect it is related to writing a file, just try commenting that part out. Usual debugging.